# Orthogonal $\cos(m\theta)$ and $\cos(n\theta)$ into polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

After 30+ years out of college, I just cracked open a book on a subject that has always intrigued me: Introduction to Orthogonal Polynomials, by Theodore S. Chihara.  I have my quibbles with his approach but let's take it on as he has presented it.

I am in the midst of proving that $\cos n\theta$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\cos(\theta)$ alone.  That's not my question, however; let's just assume it works for now.  If I now let:

(1) $x = \cos\theta$

then $\cos n\theta$, being a polynomial in $\cos\theta$, can be expressed as

(2) $T[n](x)$

since I am substituting $x$ for $\cos\theta$.  So far, so good.

Note also, that $\theta = \cos^{-1}x$ so that

(3) $$\frac{d\theta}{dx} = 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Back to the integral.

It was easy enough to prove that for integers $m$ and $n$ ($m \neq n$) then

(4) $$\int_0^\pi (\cos n\theta)(\cos m\theta)d\theta = 0$$

Now, since $x = \cos\theta$ then when

(5a) $\theta = 0$,  $x = 1$

(5b) $\theta = \pi$, $x = -1$

Thus, if I plug in $x = \cos\theta$ into the polynomials $\cos m\theta$ and $\cos n\theta$ I would get $T[m](x)$ and $T[n](x)$ in the integral, and applying the chain rule with (3), the integral becomes:

(6) $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{T[m](x) \cdot T[n](x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $$

Not the limits on the integral; these are consistent with (5a-b).

(Whew! Finally getting to the point!)

Now my problem with the book, right on the first page of chapter 1: He has the limits of the integral on the polynomial form as $[-1,1]$.

For $m\neq n$ this is OK, since the integral will be 0.  But for $m = n$, we have the perfect inner product for the vector space of this class of polynomials (Tchebichef) and, with the limits as Chihara has them, this would always be a negative number, something that should never happen in an inner product space.

Can someone point me to where I've missed a point?

Answer (score 3):

This particular version of $\arccos$ is a decreasing function on $[0, \pi]$. Its derivative is negative; you took the wrong square root.

Comment: Thank you.  I did over the derivative of arcos(theta) and I see that if theta = arcos(x) then d(theta)/dx is actually:

-1/(sqrt(1-x^2)); yes I had the sign wrong.  So by reversing the limits of the integral (to the better looking [-1:1]), the author was also correctly reversing the sign on the differential.

Again, thank you.

--J

Answer (score 2):

Also, $\cos$
has the identity
$$\cos(n \theta)
=2\cos(\theta)\cos((n-1)\theta)-\cos((n-2)\theta)
,$$
so,
if
$x 
= \cos(\theta)
$
and
$T_n(\cos(\theta))=\cos(n \theta)$,
$$T_n(x)
=2x T_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x)
.$$

This shows that,
starting with
$T_0(x) = 1$
and
$T_1(x) = 2x$,
the
$T_n(x)$
really are polynomials
of degree $n$ in $x$.